# How to connect a DSLR camera to an OpenWRT router?

Tags: openwrt

I have a TP-LINK TL-MR3020 v3 with OpenWRT already installed and a camera Nikon D5100. How to connect this camera via USB to a router, which is connected to computer (Windows 8.1) via Wi-Fi, so that such programs like Astro Photography Tool or else could see it, show LiveView and save photos on a computer?
I've tried to find something, but all I could find is DSLR Dashboard server, but is it what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it's been two hard days, but I did it.

You need to install USB/IP to your router and computer (I guess win8.1 doesn't support it) and then connect camera to router.

Detailed description at: [USB/IP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB/IP).

Also [this](https://github.com/barbalion/usbip-win-client) helped me

Comment: Nice find. I can’t test, all Macs here.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get this to work without the camera being connected directly to a computer via USB.

You need such as Capture One or Nikon's own Capture Control Pro 2 to set up the connection.

Low-end Nikons didn't have any wireless capability of their own until the D5300. The D5200 had a separate wireless transmitter you could buy. The D5100 has no wireless capability at all.

Even modern DSLRs are a long way behind 'smart' phones in connectivity terms.
They've only really since this year been generally useable as web-cams, after all the major manufacturers invested some time & effort in the pandemic to retro-equip any potentially connectible cameras with that functionality. Unfortunately, the D5100 is too old to even work under that structure - [Nikon Webcam Utility (inc supported camera list)](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/webcam-utility.page)
One thing a DSLR is not; it is not an IP camera.
It doesn't have its own on-board networking. Some have HDMI out to transmit picture, but cannot be controlled back down that same connection.

Comment: I know that this camera doesn't have Wi-Fi support, but I was thinking about to connect this camera via usb to router and connect this router to computer. I need to control camera, that is outside, from house

Comment: As I said, you need a computer connected via USB running a capture app. there's no other way. It's not an IP cam, it's a DSLR. It has no 'broadcast' functionality built-in. It also will burn out quite quickly if you try to keep Live View on all the time.

Comment: I did it! USB/IP is the solution